# Installing torch: undefined symbol for liblantern.so

Tags: 22.04, r

I try to install the R-Version of `pytorch CPU`, to avoid using `reticulate` as a workaround.
I simply used `install.packages("torch")` which successfully finished.

When using `library(torch)` after that, it states that there must be two additional system dependencies installed, e.g. `libtorch` and `liblantern`

So running `install_torch()` manually downloads both dependencies as zip files. However, then the following error occurs:

```
trying URL 'https://storage.googleapis.com/torch-lantern-builds/refs/heads/cran/v0.9.1/latest/Linux-cpu.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4844513 bytes (4.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.6 MB

/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/torch/lib/liblantern.so: undefined symbol:
  _ZNK5torch3jit6MethodclESt6vectorIN3c106IValueESaIS4_EERKSt13unordered_mapINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES4_St4hashISD_ESt8equal_toISD_ESaISt4pairIKSD_S4_EEE
```

Furthermore, I installed R using `sudo apt-get --assume-yes install -y r-base`.

I'm working on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Do you know that the file you are running is intended for Ubuntu 22.04 and that the files it is trying to download work on this version.

Comment: If you installed R from somewhere other than the Ubuntu repository, please [edit] your question to clarify how